# Scrolling view controller with Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, scroll

I have a view controller with lot of data under a navigation bar.
I want to make a transition to other view controller which looks like I'm scrolling them.
My idea is to have 3 elements at the same time and charge them into a scroll view and when I scroll to other view controller release one of them and charge another view controller to have 3 every time.
Somebody know an easier way?

Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have 3 elements, then use a single UIViewController with a scroll view that contains the 3 different element UIViews.  If you are looking to scroll through a larger set of data and want to view only 3 elements at a time, then go to a UITableViewController and implement your views as UITableViewCells.

Comment: Thank you, I think I can solve my trouble with that.